# How to get Math.min() to return the variable name instead of a number

Tags: javascript

I have five variables - organism.one, organism.two, and so on, up to five. 
They're all equal to random numbers.

I'm trying to find the smallest of them, which I can do with Math.min().

However, Math.min returns the minimal number instead of the name of the variable which holds that minimum value.

Please help, I'm very new to JavaScript. This is my code so far:

```
runt = Math.min(organism.one, organism.two, organism.three, organism.four, organism.five);
console.log("The runt is " + runt);
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. `min()` returns a number - that's what it does. Its job is to return the lowest number in a set. What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Be aware - even if  min() returned and object, your console.log function would still show `runt` as a number!

Comment: I've tried to clarify the question. Have I got you right? Also, what to return if there're two variables with minimal values?

Comment: What should be returned `one` or `organism.one`? As a note, you only have one variable here `organism` and this variable holds an object that has properties `one`, `two`, ...

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misconception about how JavaScript functions are evaluated. When you call a function such as `foo(bar)`, `foo` receives the **value** of variable `bar`, not the variable `bar` itself. `foo` doesn't know where the value came from. The following two examples are completely equivalent from the perspective of `foo`: `foo(42);` , `var bar = 42; foo(bar)`.

Comment: @nicael That's a much better way of putting it, thank you. I never plan on having two of the same number.

Comment: @Utkanos I want it to return the name of the lowest variable in the set, like "object.one"

Comment: This isn't how JS (or indeed any programming language) works. `min()` is unaware of your variable names; you feed it values, and it returns values. In other words, what you pass to `min()` is passed *by value*, not reference to the variable/property (property, in your case, not variable) that stored it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have an object with keys that contain numbers, you can use **[for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)** to iterate through them to find the smallest key:

```js
var organism = {
      one: 50,
      two: 100,
      three: 25,
      four: 15,
      five: 999
    },
    min = Infinity,
    key;
  
for(var i in organism) {
  if(organism[i] < min) {
    min = organism[i];
    key = i;
  }
}

console.log(key); //four
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is use [].reduce

```
var objects = [{
    name: 'one',
  val: 13
},
{
    name: 'two',
  val: 12
},
{
    name: 'three',
  val: 11
}];

var minimum = objects.reduce(function(obj1, obj2){ 
  return (obj1.val < obj2.val) ? obj1: obj2;        
});

console.log(minimum.val)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for all these different functions, You're very close, you just need one loop to do it:

After you get the min, loop through the object to find a match:

[JSBin Example](https://jsbin.com/mesuge/2/edit?js,console)

```
var organism = {
  two: 2,
  three: 3,
  four: 4,
  one: 1, 
  five: 5
};

var runt = Math.min(organism.one, organism.two, organism.three, organism.four, organism.five);

var lowest;
for (var org in organism) {
  if (organism[org] === runt) {
    lowest = org;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var lowestValsKey;
for(var key in organism){
    if(!lowestValsKey){
        lowestValsKey = key;
    }
    if(organism[key] < organism[lowestValsKey]){
        lowestValsKey = key;
    } 
}

console.log(lowestValsKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, perhaps you can use an object-oriented approach.

```
 var organism = { "one" : someValue, "two" : someValue, "three" : someValue, "four": someValue, "five": someValue };
 var min = null;
 var minKey = null;

 for( var key in organism ){
    if( null === min ){
        // we're at the beginning of the object, so assign min to that value.
        min = organism[key];
        minKey = key;
    }
    else if(( null !== min ) && ( organism[key] < min )){
        min = organism[key]; 
        minKey = key;
    }
 }
 console.log( "The key with the min value is: " + key + " and the value is: " + organism[key] );
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, `Math.min` only takes parameters and only returns a single number.  There is no way to make it do what you are asking for it to do.

However, if I am reading your question correctly, what you are really asking is:

> Can I pass an object to a function and get the key name of the lowest value?

If so, there is a way to do that.

```js
var organism = {
  one: 12,
  two: 19,
  three: -1,
  four: 99,
  five: 6
};

function findSmallestKey(obj) {
  var smallestKey;
  var smallestValue = Number.MAX_VALUE;

  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    var val = obj[key];
    
    if (val < smallestValue) {
       smallestValue = val;
      smallestKey = key;
    }   

  });
  
  return smallestKey;
}

var k = findSmallestKey(organism);

console.log('Smallest key is ', k);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not going to find the answer your looking for, because it's not possible.  However, you can create your own function to do it.

```js
function main(){

  function getRandom(min,max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;
  }
  
  var organism = {
    one: getRandom(1,10),
    two: getRandom(1,10),
    three: getRandom(1,10),
    four: getRandom(1,10),
    five: getRandom(1,10),
  };


  function findMin(obj){
  
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var min  = {
      name:keys[0],
      val:obj[keys[0]]
    };
              
    keys.forEach((key)=>{
      if (obj[key] < min.val)
        min={name:key,val:obj[key]};
    });
  
    return min;
  }

  var min = findMin(organism);
  document.getElementById('organisms').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(organism);
  document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = ([min.name,min.val].join(': '));
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="main();">Run</button>
<pre id="organisms"></pre>
<div id="min"></div>
```

Comment: I'm just posting this in addition to the plethora of answer because it's a fun warm-up exercise.